# Form fields not aligning correctly

Tags: html, css

[image]

If you see the image above, you will see that the input field and button are not aligning correctly. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

You can view the page at http://djkavish.com/test3/

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#bottomform input {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```